# Prompt user to open Android's Sync Service

Tags: android, synchronization

Some apps need the Location Service to be turned on & if the user is disabling it, the app will ask him to enable it & guides him to its settings like this:

[image]

So, is there any way I can prompt the user **to enable Sync Service** other than showing him only an Alert Dialog asking him to figure it out himself?